# Pass props based on a test inside a computed

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an issue with a simple test inside a `computed()` property in Nuxt 3.

```
const test = computed(() => {
  if (process.client) {
    console.log('Did work. Is mobile?', window.innerWidth < 768)
    return window.innerWidth < 768
  } else {
    console.log('Did not work')
    return
  }
})
```

The result of the computed is always correct, but then I want to use it in my template below to pass props conditionally.

```
<Loader
 v-if="isLoading"
 :images="test ? brands.desktopLoaderImages : brands.mobileLoaderImages"
/>
```

The issue is that no matter what the result is, brands.mobileLoaderImages is the one which is always going to be passed as props to my component, and I can't figure out why.

I tried to use different techniques to determine the screen size, other that `window.innerWidth`, such as dedicated modules like `@vueuse/core` but same result. I'd guess that the problem comes from the Vue lifecycle or something ?

In case this helps, here is the code inside my Loader component :

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  images: Array,
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="Loader">
    <div
      class="image"
      ref="$image"
      v-for="(n, index) in props.images"
    >
      <SanityImage
        :asset-id="images[index].asset._ref"
        alt="Loader Visual"
        auto="format"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Since `process.client` isn't reactive, why would Vue recompute the value of the test?

Comment: Hi, would you mind sharing the codes inside the Loader component?

Comment: sure! i edited my initial post to do so

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use [`useBreakpoints`](https://vueuse.org/core/useBreakpoints/#usebreakpoints) from VueUse by using its [module for nuxt](https://vueuse.org/guide/#nuxt) :

```js
const breakpoints = useBreakpoints()

const test  = breakpoints.smaller('md')
```